# Where is the generic DoesNotThrow<T> method analogous to the Throws<T> method?

Tags: c#, nunit

The [NUnit ExceptionAsserts documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5) lists several forms. Overloads aside, these forms are available:

```
Assert.Throws(/* params here, incl. delegate w/ code */)
Assert.Throws<T>(/* params here, incl. delegate w/ code */)
Assert.DoesNotThrow(/* params here, incl. delegate w/ code */)
```

I'm missing one here, this is what I'd also expect:

```
Assert.DoesNotThrow<T>(/* params here, incl. delegate w/ code */)
```

Currently I just use the `DoesNotThrow` version that's available, and pray it will never hide exceptions of a type that *does* indicate a problem. This is not satisfactory really.

I really would like to create a distinction between an exception that is relevant in the test (e.g. `Assert.DoesNotThrow<SqlException>`) and one that isn't (e.g. `NullReferenceException`). It's not a big thing, as the non-generic DoesNotThrow assertion will not affect *when* a test will be red/green, but it will affect *how* it will report being red.

Before I run off to create my own Assert extension to handle this I wanted to ask: am I missing something here? Is the form I want not available for a reason? Is it trivially achieved with other NUnit bits?

Comment: There are a near infinite number of exceptions that a test method will not throw.  Where do you begin?  Simply write a little helper method that uses try/catch to swallow all exceptions other than the one you want to test.

Comment: What @Hans said. Have you tried doing a try/catch within your test delegate to handle the exceptions that you'd consider "ok", and letting the test fail on anything that's unhandled?

Comment: Thanks for you respnses! "Where do you begin?", well at the exception the test is about, a SqlException in my scenario. I want to see a failed assert if *that* exception is thrown, and I want the test to break "normally" if any other exception is thrown. This will provide much clearer feedback in my test results (i.e. I don't want to swallow/hide other exceptions, I just want them to look different in the test results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments and lack of answers suggest that there just *is no such method* in NUnit.

As suggested in the comments you can use the `DoesNotThrow` non-generic method just ignore the fact that other types of exceptions will show the same type of output as an Assert failure.

Another suggestion from the comments was to write your own helper method, should anyone care here's one possible version:

```
public static void AssertDoesNotThrow<T>(NUnit.Framework.TestDelegate testDelegate) where T : Exception
{
    try
    {
        testDelegate.Invoke();
    }
    catch (T exception)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Expected: not an <{0}> exception or derived type.\nBut was: <{1}>",
                    typeof (T).FullName, 
                    exception.GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

For test delegates that offend the assertion you get a nice "Failure" and this type of output:

> `Expected: not an <System.ArgumentException> exception or derived type.`
>   `But was: <System.ArgumentException>`

For unexpected errors tests fail on the exception itself.

As for myself, I guess I will just accept the fact that this doesn't exist in vanilla NUnit and move on using the non-generic version.